# What is the name of the profession "creating layouts for web sites and CSS and HTML" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

What do you call this profession in English:

> someone who creates layouts for web sites in css and html

Comment: Using the "How to call" wording is unnatural and uncommon, in English. It is more common to word it as ***what** to call*?

Comment: There is no single universally accepted correct answer. Web developer, Web designer, HTML monkey, Frontend developer, and a zillion others. Everyone calls himself whatever he wants his business card to say.

Comment: And there is something common? Maybe in the dictionary, which was approved by education authorities?

Comment: English dictionaries are not approved by education authorities—they simply document the actual usage of the English language (past and present). Web developer and web designer are probably the two most common and neutral terms used, but it depends on context. Are you talking about this person specifically in comparison with someone who creates databases and database call functions for the same website? In that case, they would be the backend developers, while the HTML/CSS guy is the frontend developer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course, I can imagine a system where we dump data from a mainframe into a datamart, then import it to a wCMS for display. The DB folks are back-end to the CMS developer, who's "back-end" to the themer, who's "back-end" to the designer— but they're all "front-end" wastrels to the neckbeard working on the mainframe app.

Comment: @choster, exactly! There are so many permutations that it’s impossible to give a single, definite answer. (The other end of the scale is the geek in his mother’s basement who single-handedly assembles the server rack, writes the mainframe software, creates and handles all databases, writes his own CMS, makes the theme, and creates all graphics and copy for the website … he’s both front-, middle-, _and_ backend rolled up in one!)

Comment: The only answer to this is "Web Designer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter you use CSS/html or etc. They are all web languages for creating websites and we use Website designer or Web designer.

Comment: _Website designer_ is not particularly common overall. It is far less common than both _web developer_ and _web designer_, as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=web+designer%2Cweb+developer%2Cwebsite+designer&year_start=1996&year_end=2013&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweb%20designer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweb%20developer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebsite%20designer%3B%2Cc0) shows.

Comment: Somewhat wrong answer; Web Designer is the answer, while Web Developer is something entirely different. The person who writes the code is a developer; the person who creates the design or layout is the designer.

Answer (score 9):

You could say Web Designer.

That's probably the most popular term for it, but people have used many other terms to describe such professions, and there is no one exact universally agreed term.

Answer (score 3):

If they someone tells them almost exactly what the pages should look and they use technical skills to create the required look then they are a **Front End Web Developer**. They would often use JavaScript along with HTML and CSS, and would also work with a templating or scripting language such as Smarty or PHP.

If they decide for themselves what the pages should look like to satisfy their clients goals, then they might prefer to call themselves a **Web Designer**.

Comment: This hints at an important difference. In the early days of the web, pages were usually coded by hand by directly writing HTML, without any design tools, and creating web pages was a matter of coding or software development (often with little thought of design or visual appeal). Later the creation of web design packages like Dreamweaver meant it could be done by someone with no knowledge of HTML or programming, and this allowed designers rather than programmers/developers to create web pages. But there are still these two different ways of generating a web page with different focuses.

Comment: And today designers can create web pages by drawing pictures - either with pencil and paper or with purpose made tools such as sketch - and giving those pictures to developers for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say "UI Developer".

Comment: This would benefit from a citation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -5):

In my practice, better solution is makeuper

Comment: _Makeuper_ is not a word, and a more correct form, _make-upper_ would be a make-up artist, which is someone who puts lipstick on actresses and such things. This answer is completely and utterly wrong. You might be thinking of _markup_, but there is no noun derived from this that is commonly used to refer to web developers.

Comment: I don't understand why you would accept one answer, ignore a higher-voted answer and after eight months provide your own which makes no sense.