# (Compound) verb to add CSS so that HTML renders nicely

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests, abbreviations, technical

[Related.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147547/what-is-the-name-of-the-profession-creating-layouts-for-web-sites-and-css-and-h)

> Semantic HTML is the use of HTML markup to reinforce the semantics, or meaning, of the information in webpages and web applications rather than merely to define its presentation or look. (...) CSS is used to suggest its presentation to human users.<sup>[[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)</sup>

How do we call the act of writing/creating/applying CSS to existing semantic HTML code?

The matter may be further complicated by *CSS* being [plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40007/why-is-the-plural-acronym-css-treated-as-singular) (*Cascading Style Sheets*), so a phrase like *add a cascading style sheet* does not work. Note that in general (and specifiacally in the case I am asking about) only one style sheet is added – it just happens to be using the CSS format.

Example text: *Michael's site followed all HTML5 recommendations, so I just had to xxxxxx it.*

The verb (phrase) would be specific to CSS (as opposed to other forms of formatting), and be parallel:

- *Michael's shed was constructed with untreated wood, so I **painted** it.*
- *Michael's replacement parts are made of steel. I **galvanize** them before assembly.*
- *Michael's clothes were clean, but needed **ironing** to be presentable.*

Comment: Maybe just use *format*

Comment: @Helmar I want to be specific about CSS. OP updated.

Comment: I call applying styles ***styling***.

Comment: @michael.hor257k *... so I just had to CSS-style it*?

Comment: @Adám It depends on the context. Is it necessary to mention the technique used? If yes, I would say something like *…so I just had to style it using CSS* or  *…so I just had to style it by adding a CSS stylesheet*.

Comment: You could just use CSS as a verb: “so I just had to CSS it”.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

> Michael's site followed all HTML5 recommendations, so I just had to *style* it.

This works if the context makes it clear what you're talking about.  Otherwise, be more careful, e.g.:

> so I just had to *apply a style sheet*.

Or

> so I just had to *create a style sheet* for it. (or *create the style sheet.*)

For variety you could say

> so I just had to create the CSS.

Or

> so I just had to *define the styles*.

A web developer will understand you're talking about CSS.  The general public will not, but with such people, if you say "CSS" or "Cascading Style Sheets", that won't help *at all*.

When I want to explain CSS to the lay person, I start by asking if s/he has ever used Styles in MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

How about **decorate**.

I think this helps you solve your problem, both because the word is used to mean "add to" and it implies that the function is for aesthetics.

See the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decorate):

> Make (something) look more attractive by adding extra items or images to it.